# Are NTSC and PAL affecting games display rate or fps?

Tags: monitor, framerate

If NTSC and PAL are TV singals standards how could they affect display rate(Hz) or frames per seconds for console games (signal goes from console to tv) ? Does it still matter with hdmi?

Answer (score 1):

Internally, modern HDTVs usually support 60 frames per second.

Using an RF adapter or Composite (3 plug) plug you'll be restricted to the following:

NTSC is 60 frames per second interlaced at 640x480 resolution (480i).
PAL is 50 or 60 frames per second interlaced at (I think) 640x576 resolution (576i).

**Interlaced** means that only half the lines on the screen update on each frame.
**Progressive** means that every line updates an every frame.

Modern HDTVs have no problem doing 60fps progressive from Component (5 plug), DVI, or HDMI... or from broadcast TV channels if they're using HD.  Usually, you'll see things like 720p (1440x720 progressive) or 1080p (1920x1080 progressive).

One issue you will have is that not all **games** run at 60fps.

Answer (score 0):

NTSC and PAL are analogue standards, but is being replaced by HDTV among others.

Refresh rate wise, NTSC is 30fps and PAL is 25fps.